# Use of SVN list command without password

Tags: svn, command-line, repository

When I execute `svn list` command, it requests the password twice. I need to execute it without password. Is is possible?

Comment: maybe ask somebody for the password instead of trying to hack yourself in?

Comment: my command is                                                    `svn list svn+ssh://svn.sts.com.jo/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/core`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you're using `svn+ssh://`. That means the password prompts are actually coming from ssh, not svn itself. So the first thing you need to do is configure ssh for passwordless authentication. The most common way to do that is using public keys.

The svn manual [has some tips for configuring public key access](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshtricks).

For debugging any problems with the ssh access, it's sometimes useful to run ssh by hand, like this: `ssh -v svn.sts.com.jo svnserve -t`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either try to use the username and password arguments, or use the `--non-interactive` switch:

```
svn list <url> --non-interactive
svn list <url> --username <user> --pass <pass>
```